# Exporting DataTable using FileHelpers

Tags: .net, filehelpers

I want to export the contents of a DataTable to a text delimited file using FileHelpers, is this possible? Here is what I have so far:

```
// dt is a DataTable with Rows in it
DelimitedClassBuilder cb = new DelimitedClassBuilder("MyClassName", "|", dt);
Type t = cb.CreateRecordClass();
FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(t);
```

I have to convert the contents of dt to an array of type "MyClassName" but I'm not sure how to do that? I know there is a FileDataLink class but none of them work with DataTable (or even a DataSet).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you could use this:

```
CommonEngine.DataTableToCsv(dt, "customers.csv", '|');
```